# My index.php running on mamp server is not loading any javascript files for my page

Tags: javascript, php, html, localhost, mamp

my index.php running on my mamp server is not loading any javascript files I have in my project. I should also add I am learning this as I go. I have good experience with html but I'm new to combining html with php.

I had to link an html form to an email using php. In order to do that I had to change my index.html to index.php which required me to run mamp in order to view the webpage.

Now that I have the webpage running on my localhost server the page is not running any of my javascript files in my project.

The file structure is comprised as follows:
project/
        css/style.css
        fonts/
        img/image files
        js/script.js , and other .js files
        index.php

Here is my form section inside of js/script.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip-down").click(function(){
      $("#flip-down-panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
```

```css
#flip-down-panel, #flip-down {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  }
  
  #flip-down-panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none; /* <<<<< remove this line to view what's suppose to display
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>contactform</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 id="flip-down">
        <font color="black">CONTACT ME</font>
      </h2>
      <div id="flip-down-panel">
        <form action="contactform.php" method="POST">
          <h3>Tell Me Something</h3>
          <div class="row">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <?php
            if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
              $name = $_GET['name'];
              echo '<input name="name" type="username" placeholder="First Name" value="'.$name.'">';
            } else {
              echo '<input name="name"type="username" placeholder="First Name">';
            }
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <label>Email</label>
            <?php
            if (isset($_GET['email'])) {
              $email = $_GET['email'];
              echo '<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" value="'.$email.'">';
            } else {
              echo '<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address">';
            }
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <label>Message</label>
            <?php
            if (isset($_GET['message'])) {
              $message = $_GET['message'];
              echo '<textarea type="text" placeholder="Write message" value="'.$message.'"></textarea>';
            } else {
              echo '<textarea type="text" placeholder="Write message"></textarea>';
            }
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sub" value="Send Message">
          </div>
        </form>
        <?php
        if (!isset($_GET['contactUs'])) {
          exit();
        } else {
          $contactUsCheck = $_GET['contactUs'];
          if ($contactUsCheck == "empty") {
            echo '<p class="error">You MUST fill out all fields!</p>';
            exit();
          } elseif ($contactUsCheck == "char") {
            echo '<p class="error">You used invalid characters for Name!</p>';
            exit();
          } elseif ($contactUsCheck == "invalidemail") {
            echo '<p class="error">You entered an invalid email!</p>';
            exit();
          } elseif ($contactUsCheck == "mailsent") {
            echo '<p class="success">Your message has been sent!</p>';
            exit();
          }
        }
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--FOOTER-->
  <section>
    <div id="flip-down">
        <div>Copy Right stuffs</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Open the browser, run you page, press F12  key, look in the Console tab and what error message, if any, is displayed. If you have reported your folder structure correctly then change include '../js/script.js'; to include 'js/script.js'; and see if that helps.

Comment: @jeff I am getting an error called 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT' and those seem to be from the embedded player for youtube on the page

Comment: I don't think you've posted enough of your HTML to make a diagnosis. Where and how are you referencing your JavaScript e.g., `<script src="foo.js">`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not all that experienced in PHP myself, but if I'm not mistaken, `include` just plops the contents of the file into the location that it is called. Instead of including the JS file in PHP, try just creating an HTML tag like so:

```html
<script src="/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**EDIT:** In regards to your updated code, I noticed that in your CSS and HTML you have 2 IDs, `flip-down` and `flip-down-panel`, but in your JS, you only have `flip` and `panel`. After changing the selectors in the JavaScript to `flip-down` and `flip-down-panel` respectively, the example you posted works fine.

Just as a side note, IDs are only meant to be unique across all DOM elements, so if you have an ID that needs to be used more than once like `flip-down`, I would recommend changing it to a class so it doesn't cause issues with JavaScript when you try to reference everything with that ID.

One last thing, put the script tag that references JQuery before the one that uses it, as it has to be loaded before it can be used.

Comment: Ok so I moved the dependencies above the php tags but it didnt change anything. I tried commenting out the bottom php block containing the big if statement that I posted above and fixed one thing which was displaying the page footer after the section. I also tested removing the <div id="flip-down-panel"> from the code and that basically fixed the problem I'm having of triggering the javascript that the id is connected to on the js side

Comment: Could you possibly share more of your PHP file? I've suggested pretty much everything I can think of without making drastic assumptions about your implementation.

Comment: I made an edit to the post, not sure if you saw it @jesse . I can post more of the PHP file if needed though

Comment: I just updated my answer if you would like to take a look at it and give me your thoughts :) @MichaelAguayo

Comment: Hey I just saw the edits and I edited my post again to fix the js. It does work now but what is strange is that it still does not work in my project while running on the MAMP server. 

As for the ID sidenote, I just followed this from w3schools to achieve this 
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle)

Answer (score 0):

Load your js files like you probably always did: `<script src="js/script.js"></script>`

If you really want it to be included directly in php (can't see a real reason to do so, but you can..) make sure you include it in between `<script>` tag like so:

```
...
<label class="sr-only">Name</label>
    <script>
        <?php 
            include 'js/script.js';
        ?>
    </script>
    <?php
        if( isset($_GET['name']) ) {
        ...
```

Also make sure the path to file is correct